# Module.exports to export variables in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have two javascript files. a1.js and utils.js
The files are as follows:

a1.js

```
const namet = require('./utils.js')
console.log(name);
```

utils.js

```
console.log('utils.js');
const name ='Mike';
module.exports = name;
```

When I run this file I get an error message

```
ReferenceError: name is not defined
```

The only way I avoid the error message is if I change the require line in a1.js to say:

```
const name = require('./utils.js')
```

What am I doing wrong? I thought that the name of the require const should not matter. I am using node version 10.1.0

Comment: can't reproduce ... running `node a1` outputs `utils.js` and `Mike` as expected

Comment: which version of node do you have?

Comment: The current recommended LTS version

Comment: sorry, i had an error when i copied over the code. please see now. I was doing console.log(namet) instead of console.log(name); i have edited the quetion to correct it

Comment: well ... of course `name` is undefined, since you declare a variable called `namet` ... try `const name = require('./utils.js')`

Comment: think of `utils.js` as doing this: `module.exports = 'Mike';` ... now ... how is the name of the const being `name` at all relevant? it isn't and it never was

Answer (score 0):

Rename `name` on line 2 to `namet`

```
const namet = require('./utils.js')
console.log(namet);
```

Comment: or namet->name on line 1 :p